# I can't run my code cause of classpath build.gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have migrated to new version of flutter, and faced lots of problems with migrating projects. now,i can't solve the last.  When I try to run my project is gives error as following:  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.

I checked android/build.gradle and my dependencies as following:
`dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5' classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" }`
also, my gradle-wrapper.properties:
`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/d`your text`ists distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`

I have tried commands as clear, upgrade, create . and other stuff. but nothing is helping me at all